# REST vs Dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, spring

I developed a dynamic web project in eclipse java EE ide as index.jsp, when I run it on Tomcat Server7.0 server it says http://localhost:8080/filename/ something. is that what they mean by REST? or do I need Spring to run a REST ?. rest is what that comes in a url, if i provide this url in my browser it opens the file, then why I can't call it as rest service?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Answer (score 0):

Restful is an architectural style that make in disposition through HTTP a number of resources under different formats, usually json, to set or retrive the ressources, simple http operations (PUT, GET, POST, and DELETE. PUT) could be used for that.

I recommend you to use JAX-RS, but here u can see how to work with rest web service with Spring:

[Building a RESTful Web Service Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: Thankyou, but i've already tried that program. displaying helloworld. it just took time to figure out, how it actually works, like if i produce, www.facebook.com/?username=something&password=something then after my website directory www.faacebook.com the data i provide will be taken as a input to fill the two text boxes, i.e iam sending a data in the url and that is posted in the two field boxes. rite?, there is POST being used. that will not be happening if i do in some.jsp and running it on local server rite?. if this comment is correct, pls comment yes. if not pls make me understand it. ty

Comment: Rest its different, you have resources lets say users, and u makes web-services with the methods u want, u can put out resources as being objects lets say in ur case users, using rest, the resources can be in various formats, lets say json, and its client/server architecture, u can just get, or manipulate data, that is being given as resources, and do what ever u want with, regardless the programming language u are working with (with web services, clients could have any programming language), and send back using also http.